# Балтия или Прибалтика?

Tags: ономастика, топонимика

«Балтия, особенно Литва» или «Прибалтика, особенно Литва»? Как правильно?

Answer (score 3):

**Балтия**
В современном русском языке (с начала девяностых) это название используется только для трёх государств (трёх республик): Эстонии, Латвии и *Литвы*.

**Прибалтика** ([Большая актуальная политическая энциклопедия](https://greater_political.academic.ru/153/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D0%91%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%90))

> Однако в историческом, политическом и культурологическом смыслах этот термин сейчас применяется для обозначения земель, расположенных на восточном побережье Балтики — *Литвы*, Латвии, Эстонии и Калининградской области Российской Федерации.

Абстрагируемся от географических и политических споров и примем решение: Балтия — это кусок Прибалтики, а Литва — это часть и Балтии, и Прибалтики. Так что верны оба предложения.

> Так или иначе, слова обоих политиков вызвали тревогу **в Балтии, особенно в Литве**, поскольку «младоевропейцы», как известно, являются самыми горячими сторонниками европейской интеграции Украины, Молдовы и Грузии, о которых Меркель и Юнкер будто забыли.

> При этом в качестве доказательства агрессивности России и в Польше и **в Прибалтике (особенно в Литве)** постоянно ссылаются на «милитаризацию» нашей Калининградской области.

P. S. Я живу в Эстонии (*Eesti Vabariik*), и всегда обозначаю свою страну как часть Прибалтики (можно посмотреть профиль). Балтия — красиво, понятно, но почему-то не моё.

Comment: *И не моё тоже.*

Comment: Спасибо, Римма. Когда один и тот же звук относится к двум неравновеликим понятиям, то это выглядит несерьёзно: в 60-х в стране появилось моющее средство с одноимённым названием. Оно было весьма популярным. Давший имя бутылочке не мог заглянуть в будущее, но современники... должны же иметь представление об истории слова, истории бренда. Заглянул на https://ru.frwiki.wiki/wiki/Pays_baltes? и ужаснулся качеству текстов, местами непролазных. Было бы здорово навести там порядок. Вам сподручнее, да и кому, как не Вам.

Answer (score 0):

О термине «**Прибалтика**» известно (из энциклопедии на academic.ru), что в историческом, политическом и культурологическом смыслах он сейчас применяется для обозначения *земель*, расположенных на восточном побережье Балтики — Литвы, Латвии, Эстонии и Калининградской области России.

Далее читаем, что государств на побережье Балтийского моря (кроме Латвии, Эстонии и Литвы) ещё пять... Применяемый исключительно в отношении трёх бывших республик бывшего Советского Союза, термин «**Страны Балтии**» внедряется совершенно неоправданно ни в географическом, ни в историческом смысле.

На https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltic_states пишется о термине «**Балтийский**», гидрониме III века до н.э., упомянутом Эрастотеном как *Балтия* в древнегреческом тексте (*baltas* по-литовски и *balts* по-латышски означают «белый»). Однако современные названия региона и моря, происходящие от этого корня, не использовались ни в одном из двух языков до XIX века.

И там же — о мере взимодействия в наши дни: «Термин не используется в контексте культурной зоны, национальной принадлежности, или же языка. <...> Три страны не образуют официального союза, но участвуют в межправительственном и парламентском сотрудничестве».

В статье «Балтия (значения)» слово представлено как топоним от нем. Baltia (вариант нем. Basilia), связываемый в Германии либо с одним из наименований города Базель, либо с городом в Нидерландах, либо с островом (возможно, вымышленным) близ балтийского побережья Пруссии. Варианта Балты, реального городка в Одесской области, в перечне нет.